# How to jump from system push notifications settings to personal push notifications settings in the application?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I saw such buttons in some applications in the push notifications settings, which open the personal notification settings in the application.
I could not find information on how to implement this. Please tell me how to add this to my application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NldWd.jpg)

Comment: Even i want to implement same, can you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the request notification authorization you should add `providesAppNotificationSettings` like below.

> UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound, .providesAppNotificationSettings])

After that you need to redirect user to your app's settings page below function.

> ```
> func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) { // Redirect User to App Settings Page}
> ```